# How can I create a macOS SwiftUI button with the NSRefreshTemplate image?

Tags: swiftui, sf-symbols

I can't figure out how to access the NSRefreshTemplate image for a SwiftUI button.  Is there some way to access system images ?

```
Button(action: {
  print("Do something...")
}) {
    Image("NSRefreshTemplate")
}.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
```

Where do SF Symbols fit with these system images and how does one access these SF Symbols?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as shown below

```
Button(action: {
  print("Do something...")
}) {
   Image(nsImage: NSImage(named: NSImage.refreshTemplateName)!)
}.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
```